# I get error when using "lstbox" in Skype Bot code using SKYPECOM4lib

Tags: vba

When I use lstbox in VBA code for a skype bot using skype api lib and stuff I get this error. Also I saw a youtuber use it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ahkuYT7-wdU) and im using the same lib as him and same code.

[Code with error](https://i.gyazo.com/a0a08ea6af82ac10e98ba03f4c1142b6.png)

Comment: Your question is quite unclear, maybe a little bit of finetuning in [these](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/advice-for-non-native-english-speakers/291370#291370) could help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out. Change it to ListBox1